# Weaker term than concluded

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

> I thought about the situation and concluded...

Concluded seems too strong for the situation I am using this in. In particular, in view of the hierarchy between me and my conversation partner.

What is a good synonym to tone this down?

The word I would like to use is "think" but I have used that already in the sentence. Other synonyms "decide, establish, determine" are all not weaker than conclude. It need not be a single word solution.

Comment: Which synonyms have you already considered?

Comment: decide, establish, determine are all not weaker

Comment: Surmise, suppose

Comment: There are many options. Did you think about it and reach a conclusion? Did you just think? Did you sense or feel something? Did you judge? Did you decide or choose? Did you suddenly see something new?

Comment: I thought about the situation and **point to the conclusion that ...**

Comment: Concluded is to decided as concurred is to agreed. More everyday language.

Comment: _Come to a tentative/preliminary/possible conclusion that `S`_ does nicely. That's what those qualifying adjectives are for, and why one wants a noun for them to modify.

Comment: *feel*.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way of expressions there is a large choice of possibilities, and those seem better choices. Here are a few.

- I got the idea that
- I got the impression that
- I came to think that
- It occurred to me that
- I was driven to think that

*Single word terms*

- I understood that (*but of course that is just my understanding*)
- I fathomed that (*rather formal*)
- I grasped that
- I glimpsed